# RoR: Saving rendered emails as HTML for linking in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, newsletter

Like it is in many newsletter services, I want to use Ruby on Rails to write a Newsletter. Now I want to provide a link in this email to view this newsletter in a browser, if the email is not shown correctly in Email Client. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to include a link in e-mail, or how to display the newsletter on your site.  I'll try to give some basic advice on each.

E-mail views use erb by default, just like page views on your site.  Therefore, you add dynamic content the same way.  If your e-mail goes out in HTML format:

```
<%= link_to 'View Online', newsletter_url(@newsletter) %>
```

If it goes out in plaintext format:

```
<%= newsletter_url(@newsletter) %>
```

Even in plaintext format, URLs and e-mail addresses are made clickable by most e-mail clients.

Of course, this means your newsletter should be stored in the database like any other model, with a controller and views.  Use the "show" action for displaying the newsletter to viewers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, my problem is how to display the email on my site. So I didn't have any idea on how to do this. But thanks to your advise, I will now try to create a controller which renders the mail templates for the Browser.